# Issue with google Reseller API sending batch requests

Tags: google-reseller-api

In a special scenario wherein the resold customer who is using Google Vault, GoogleDrive along with Google Apps for Business, and to transfer that customer, as per the documentation (Ref https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/batch) we're supposed to use Batch Subscription Ordering.

Here is what we're observing so far:

1. When we try to transfer resold customer which has only one subscription “Google-Apps-For-Business” 
   a.       Then the Batch Ordering (even though its not required) is working.
2. However when we have to transfer resold customer who has more than on subscription such as “Google-Apps-for-Business” and one or more of “Google Vault”, “Google drive”
   a.       If we send all features request with Batch Order, the call retunes Error Code: 500 (Internal Server Error) 
   b.      If we send only one request (even though it is wrong as per the documentation) in the Batch Order (the Google-apps-for-business), the call returns expected Error Code: 412 (Precondition Failed): The domain has subscriptions which need to be transferred.

We also tried based on the Google Calendar API Example (Ref https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/batch) but it also results in the same failure.

Both above suggests either the documentation is wrong or the API doesn't work as per the documentation.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Here is the sample code

```
// based on https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Batch sample code
Reseller reseller = Reseller.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("RedResellerAccountSample").build();
JsonBatchCallback<Subscription>; callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Subscription>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Subscription t,
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Success");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e,
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Failure");
    }
};
BatchRequest batchRequest = reseller.batch();
Subscription sub = new Subscription();
sub.setKind("subscriptions#subscription");
sub.setCustomerId("testdomain.com");

Subscription.Plan plan = new Subscription.Plan();
plan.setPlanName("TRIAL");

Seats seats = new Seats();
seats.setKind("subscriptions#seats");
seats.setMaximumNumberOfSeats(10);

sub.setPlan(plan);
sub.setSeats(seats);
sub.setSkuId("Google-Apps-For-Business");

reseller.subscriptions().insert("testdomain.com",sub).setCustomerAuthToken("B40D2EFF4316B703").queue(batchRequest, callback);
Subscription sub2 = new Subscription();
sub2.setKind("subscriptions#subscription");
sub2.setCustomerId("testdomain.com");

Subscription.Plan plan2 = new Subscription.Plan();
plan2.setPlanName("TRIAL");

Seats seats2 = new Seats();
seats2.setKind("subscriptions#seats");
seats2.setMaximumNumberOfSeats(10);

sub2.setPlan(plan);
sub2.setSeats(seats);
sub2.setSkuId("Google-Vault");

reseller.subscriptions().insert("testdomain.com",sub2).setCustomerAuthToken("B40D2EFF4316B703").queue(batchRequest, callback);

//System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(batchRequest);

// if we call it fail as we have more than one request queued in the
batchRequest.execute();
```

Comment: Could you post some code showing what you have tried please.

Comment: I am still waiting for the solution. Any body has suggestion?

Comment: A bug with Google has been triaged on this issue for Reseller API batch operation.

Batch operation should work with Calendar API.  Can you show us your code for Calendar API?